# What is the input order for keys in reduce() method

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a simple use case. In my input file I just need to calculate the percentage distribution of total number of words. For example word1 is present 10 times, word2 is present 5 times etc and the total number of words are 100 then I just need to display % word1 = 10 % , % word2 = 5% etc. So whenever I encounter a word I just put context.write(word,1) in map() and in the reduce I sum up the individual counts. But to calculate the percentage we require total number of words. I am also calculating that.

Hence before getting the keys for word1 or word2 in the reduce I am to get the total word count key for percentage calculation for each and every word. But in the reduce I am getting this total words key after some other keys. Hence I am unable to calculate the percentage.

I also tried to set this total count in the config of map using context.getConfiguration().setFloat("total count",count); But in the reduce I am not able to get this value from config. It simply returns null.

Any suggestions please add.

thank you..

Comment: You could try using a Counter instead of setting values in the Configuration. For each word in the Mappers, just increment the Counter, then get the value in the Reducers.

Comment: By the way, the input order for keys is sorted based on the default comparator. So if it's Text, then lexicographical order. However, each key will only go to one Reducer, so you can't just output the total word count as a key if you want your code to work with more than one Reducer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first *digest* your document, like this:

```
class WordCounter {
    Map<String, Integer> totals = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int wordCount;

    void digest(String document) {
        for (String word : document.split("\\w+")) {
            wordCount++;
            Integer count = totals.get(word);
            if (count == null)
                totals.put(word, 1);
            else
                totals.put(word, ++count);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do a second pass over your document doing what you like with the info you've collected, perhaps using something like this method on every word:

```
String decorateWithPercent(String word) {
    return word + " (" + (totals.get(word) / wordCount) + "%)";
}
```

Or to print the frequencies, something like:

```
void printFrequencies() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> wordCount : totals.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(wordCount.getKey() + " " + wordCount.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion. I want to implement the logic in map reduce using single pass as the file I want to scan is 15GB.